# Im2txt: Using TFRecords of preprocessed MSCOCO dataset to perform captioning

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to perform a captioning on the MSCOCO validation set, with the open source **`Im2txt`** model

> https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt

I was wondering if is it possible to exploit the validation set `TFRecord` shards generated by the `MSCOCO` preprocessing script

e.g. `val-0000*-of-00008` to do this, since captioning a large set of JPEG files takes too long.

How can I adapt a **`run_inference.py`** to handle `SequenceExamples` instead of JPG or PNG files?